# Magento2 - Translate in js

Tags: magento2.3

In my file `app/design/frontend/vender/name/Magento_Newsletter/templates/subscribe.phtml`

I have written...

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/translate',
    'domReady!'
], function($, _) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var CaptchaCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('RecaptchaField', {
            'sitekey': '<?= $siteKey ?>'
        });
        };
        window.CaptchaCallback = CaptchaCallback;
    });
    
    $(document).on('submit', '#newsletter-validate-detail', function(){
        var isSubmit = jQuery(this).valid() && grecaptcha.getResponse() != '';
        if (!isSubmit) {
            document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML= $.mage.__('Please click on the 
reCAPTCHA!');
            return false;
        }
        return isSubmit;
    });
})
</script>
```

and translate `i18n`

```
"Please click on the reCAPTCHA!","Bitte klicken Sie auf das reCAPTCHA!"
```

But It's not working. It only show error "Please click on the reCAPTCHA!". Don't know if I'm missing anything? Please help me!

Comment: Especially in developer mode javascript translation isn't the most stable did you try `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` ?

Comment: yes i have run it

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer - move JavaScript to  .js file as per best practices, or translate using PHP (don’t forget to escape!).

JS translations are collected statically into js-translation.json file  using regular expression match on static files like .js and .html. PHTML files are not scanned because server can translate them on backend.

See Magento\Translation\Model\Js\DataProvider::getPhrases

Called somewhere in
\Magento\Deploy\Model\Deploy\LocaleDeploy::deploy $this->deployFile($dictionaryFileName, $area, $themePath, $locale, null);
\Magento\Translation\Model\Js\PreProcessor::process
\Magento\Deploy\Model\Deploy\LocaleDeploy::deployFile

Regular expressions:

```
<type name="Magento\Translation\Model\Js\Config">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="patterns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="i18n_translation" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[~(?:i18n\:|_\.i18n\()\s*(["'])(.*?)(?<!\\)\1~]]></item>
            <item name="translate_wrapping" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[~translate\=("')([^\'].*?)\'\"~]]></item>
            <item name="mage_translation_widget" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[~(?s)(?:\$|jQuery)\.mage\.__\(\s*(['"])(?<translate>.+?)(?<!\\)\1\s*(*SKIP)\)\s*(?s)~]]></item>
            <item name="mage_translation_static" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[~(?s)\$t\(\s*(['"])(?<translate>.+?)(?<!\\)\1\s*(*SKIP)\)(?s)~]]></item>
            <item name="translate_args" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[~translate args\=("|'|"'|\\"')([^\'].*?)('\\"|'"|'|")~]]></item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Also, because of how it parses static strings, it’s impossible to translate using variable texts.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the js-translation.json file has not re-generated correctly. For development purposes, it is safe to delete js-translation.json from pub/static/frontend/Magento/theme/lang_code.

If you then flush the Magento cache and refresh the front-end of the website, this allows the setup:static-content:deploy lang_codes to correctly generate the file